# unable to run the sql query in hibernate hql query

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using hibernate hql where below query has to be implemented as hql where the doctor user id is mapped to rdo_user user_id in one to many mapping

```
select * from rdo.rdo_user as u , rdo.doctor d where u.user_id=d.user_id;
```

My HQL QUERY IS

```
         String sql = "select user,doc from RdoUser as user, Doctor as doc";
    if(search_doctor != null){
        sql = sql+" where user.userId=doc.userId and (LOWER(user.firstName) like '%"+ search_doctor +"%' or LOWER(user.lastName) like '%"+ search_doctor +"%' or LOWER(user.email) like '%"+ search_doctor +"%')";
    }
```

kindly guide me how to achieve this

error which i am facing is

```
         Feb 16, 2016 9:57:51 PM com.caucho.hessian.io.SerializerFactory getDeserializer
         WARNING: Hessian/Burlap: 'org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate' is an unknown class in WebappClassLoader
         context: 
        delegate: false
        repositories:
        /WEB-INF/classes/
        ----------> Parent Classloader:
        java.net.URLClassLoader@8afcd0c
         :
         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate
```

Comment: what is the error? And where is the "select" part in your `String sql`?

Comment: no i have changed the query with select but i could not able to retrive the values from the table and i am not finding any errors on both the cases